# discord.py бот должен выдать роль на нажатие реакции

Tags: python, discord.py

сделал команду marry:

```
@bot.command()
async def marry(ctx, member: disnake.Member):
    embed = disnake.Embed(title=f":ring:согласны ли вы? o((^▽^))o", description= f"*Участник:* {ctx.author.name} решил предложить {member.name} жениться.(っ.❛ ᴗ ❛.)っ", color=0xFFFFFE)
    embed.set_image(url='https://smolensk-i.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/svadba.jpg')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

но не могу понять как сделать так чтобы:
когда нужный участник **(member: disnake.Member)** нажимал бы на роль, бот написал бы: вы поженились!
и выдал бы обоим роль.
либо же нажал на реакцию крестик и написало бы: {member.name} не согласился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def marry(ctx, member: disnake.Member):
    embed = disnake.Embed(title=f":ring:согласны ли вы? o((^▽^))o", description= f"*Участник:* {ctx.author.name} решил предложить {member.name} жениться.(っ.❛ ᴗ ❛.)っ", color=0xFFFFFE)
    embed.set_image(url='https://smolensk-i.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/svadba.jpg')
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')

    def check(arg):
        if member.id == arg.user_id:
            return str(arg.emoji) == '✅' or str(arg.emoji) == '❌'
    try:
        payload = await bot.wait_for('raw_reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        if str(payload.emoji) == '✅':
            await ctx.author.add_roles('role')
            await member.add_roles('role')
            await ctx.send("вы поженились!")
        elif str(payload.emoji) = '❌':
            await ctx.send(f"{member.name} не согласился")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Время вышло!')
```

Comment: Можете объяснить что делает в этом коде функция `check`?